# Memory error occured after AHT

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, apple-hardware-test

I have MacBook Pro 6,2 mid-2010 15-inch with Core i7 2.66GHz, 8GB Ram, 240GB SSD. Since it doesn't support a later OS than High Sierra it became useless and I wanted to use Linux on it, but before I go with Linux I had some issues like freezing, etc. And I experienced the same problems on Linux too, so I decided to run AHT and I found a memory error which is 'Failure Code: 4MEM/66/40000000: 0xa50c6e18'

ERROR:
[image]

RAMs:
[image]

I am not sure what to do, because it is not clear which RAM or Slot (maybe logic board) is faulty, I want to use this device because it is still worth it, it is a victim of Planned Obsolescence. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Win10 still work on it.

Here is the [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/rember/) Test result.

```
Memtest version 4.22 (64-bit)
Copyright (C) 2004 Charles Cazabon
Copyright (C) 2004-2008 Tony Scaminaci (Macintosh port)
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 only

Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G66) running in multiuser mode
Memory Page Size: 4096
System has 4 Intel core(s) with SSE
Requested memory: 3452MB (3620372480 bytes)
Available memory: 3452MB (3620372480 bytes)
Allocated memory: 3452MB (3620372480 bytes) at local address 0x0000000108ee2000
Attempting memory lock... locked successfully
Partitioning memory into 2 comparison buffers...
Buffer A: 1726MB (1810186240 bytes) starts at local address 0x0000000108ee2000
Buffer B: 1726MB (1810186240 bytes) starts at local address 0x0000000174d36000

Running 1 test sequence... (CTRL-C to quit)

Test sequence 1 of 1:

Running tests on full 3452MB region...
  Stuck Address       :                 setting  1 of 16testing  1 of 16setting  2 of 16testing  2 of 16setting  3 of 16testing  3 of 16setting  4 of 16testing  4 of 16setting  5 of 16testing  5 of 16setting  6 of 16testing  6 of 16setting  7 of 16testing  7 of 16setting  8 of 16testing  8 of 16setting  9 of 16testing  9 of 16setting 10 of 16testing 10 of 16setting 11 of 16testing 11 of 16setting 12 of 16testing 12 of 16setting 13 of 16testing 13 of 16setting 14 of 16testing 14 of 16setting 15 of 16testing 15 of 16setting 16 of 16testing 16 of 16                ok
  Linear PRN          :    setting  1 of 16testing  1 of 16setting  2 of 16testing  2 of 16setting  3 of 16testing  3 of 16setting  4 of 16testing  4 of 16setting  5 of 16testing  5 of 16setting  6 of 16testing  6 of 16setting  7 of 16testing  7 of 16setting  8 of 16testing  8 of 16setting  9 of 16testing  9 of 16setting 10 of 16testing 10 of 16setting 11 of 16testing 11 of 16setting 12 of 16testing 12 of 16setting 13 of 16testing 13 of 16setting 14 of 16testing 14 of 16setting 15 of 16testing 15 of 16setting 16 of 16testing 16 of 16                ok
Running comparison tests using 1726MB buffers...
  Random Value        :    \|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\| ok
  Compare XOR         :       ok
  Compare SUB         :       ok
  Compare MUL         :       ok
  Compare DIV         :       ok
  Compare OR          :       ok
  Compare AND         :       ok
  Sequential Increment:       ok
  Solid Bits          :                 setting  1 of 64testing  1 of 64setting  2 of 64testing  2 of 64setting  3 of 64testing  3 of 64setting  4 of 64testing  4 of 64setting  5 of 64testing  5 of 64setting  6 of 64testing  6 of 64setting  7 of 64testing  7 of 64setting  8 of 64testing  8 of 64setting  9 of 64testing  9 of 64setting 10 of 64testing 10 of 64setting 11 of 64testing 11 of 64setting 12 of 64testing 12 of 64setting 13 of 64testing 13 of 64setting 14 of 64testing 14 of 64setting 15 of 64testing 15 of 64setting 16 of 64testing 16 of 64setting 17 of 64testing 17 of 64setting 18 of 64testing 18 of 64setting 19 of 64testing 19 of 64setting 20 of 64testing 20 of 64setting 21 of 64testing 21 of 64setting 22 of 64testing 22 of 64setting 23 of 64testing 23 of 64setting 24 of 64testing 24 of 64setting 25 of 64testing 25 of 64setting 26 of 64testing 26 of 64setting 27 of 64testing 27 of 64setting 28 of 64testing 28 of 64setting 29 of 64testing 29 of 64setting 30 of 64testing 30 of 64setting 31 of 64testing 31 of 64setting 32 of 64testing 32 of 64setting 33 of 64testing 33 of 64setting 34 of 64testing 34 of 64setting 35 of 64testing 35 of 64setting 36 of 64testing 36 of 64setting 37 of 64testing 37 of 64setting 38 of 64testing 38 of 64setting 39 of 64testing 39 of 64setting 40 of 64testing 40 of 64setting 41 of 64testing 41 of 64setting 42 of 64testing 42 of 64setting 43 of 64testing 43 of 64setting 44 of 64testing 44 of 64setting 45 of 64testing 45 of 64setting 46 of 64testing 46 of 64setting 47 of 64testing 47 of 64setting 48 of 64testing 48 of 64setting 49 of 64testing 49 of 64setting 50 of 64testing 50 of 64setting 51 of 64testing 51 of 64setting 52 of 64testing 52 of 64setting 53 of 64testing 53 of 64setting 54 of 64testing 54 of 64setting 55 of 64testing 55 of 64setting 56 of 64testing 56 of 64setting 57 of 64testing 57 of 64setting 58 of 64testing 58 of 64setting 59 of 64testing 59 of 64setting 60 of 64testing 60 of 64setting 61 of 64testing 61 of 64setting 62 of 64testing 62 of 64setting 63 of 64testing 63 of 64setting 64 of 64testing 64 of 64                ok
  Block Sequential    :                   setting   1 of 256testing   1 of 256setting   2 of 256testing   2 of 256setting   3 of 256testing   3 of 256setting   4 of 256testing   4 of 256setting   5 of 256testing   5 of 256setting   6 of 256testing   6 of 256setting   7 of 256testing   7 of 256setting   8 of 256testing   8 of 256setting   9 of 256testing   9 of 256setting  10 of 256testing  10 of 256setting  11 of 256testing  11 of 256setting  12 of 256testing  12 of 256setting  13 of 256testing  13 of 256setting  14 of 256testing  14 of 256setting  15 of 256testing  15 of 256setting  16 of 256testing  16 of 256setting  17 of 256testing  17 of 256setting  18 of 256testing  18 of 256setting  19 of 256testing  19 of 256setting  20 of 256testing  20 of 256setting  21 of 256testing  21 of 256setting  22 of 256testing  22 of 256setting  23 of 256testing  23 of 256setting  24 of 256testing  24 of 256setting  25 of 256testing  25 of 256setting  26 of 256testing  26 of 256setting  27 of 256testing  27 of 256setting  28 of 256testing  28 of 256setting  29 of 256testing  29 of 256setting  30 of 256testing  30 of 256setting  31 of 256testing  31 of 256setting  32 of 256testing  32 of 256setting  33 of 256testing  33 of 256

FAILURE! Data mismatch at local BUFA address 0x000000014efece18, BUFB address 0x00000001bae40e18
BUFA Data: 0x2020202020202020, BUFB Data: 0x2020202020200020

  Checkerboard        :                 setting  1 of 64
```

Edit: I followed the suggestion of @Tetsujin and i found the faulty RAM, seems like my problems are solved, and i think heating problem is solved too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard procedure to test RAM…

Remove one stick.
Test the other, in both slots.
Swap sticks.
Test again in both slots.

This will determine which stick, or whether it's the slot or motherboard failing.

Comment: it will take a lot of times with ATH's long test, but i will do it, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: i did, as you suggested. One of the RAM passed the test on both slots, other one gave error on lower slot and AHT got stucked on upper slot, so i removed the RAM, it is now working on 4GB ram but working better than 8gb now :) some apps didnt open on 8gb RAM now opening on 4gb RAM, i was suffering with 8gb. Thank you.

Comment: i contacted to Crucial, they seems caring.